# python: get the print output in an exec statement

Tags: python, printing, exec

I want to get the output of an `exec(...)` Here is my code:

```
code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
    print j
"""
result = exec(code)
```

How could I get the things that print outputed?
How can I get something like:

```
0
1
2
```

Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Since Python 3.4 there is a solution is the stdlib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout

```
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

f = StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    help(pow)
s = f.getvalue()
```

In older versions you can write a context manager to handle replacing stdout:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdoutIO(stdout=None):
    old = sys.stdout
    if stdout is None:
        stdout = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = stdout
    yield stdout
    sys.stdout = old

code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
    print j
"""
with stdoutIO() as s:
    exec(code)

print("out:", s.getvalue())
```

Comment: i've got a :File "D:\Documents\perso\dev\meta\Server.py", line 77, in decompress_html
    with self.stdoutIO() as s:
AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: @user462794: It seems you ignored the `@contextlib.contextmanager` line

Comment: You should wrap the last two lines of the generator function in try-finally, though.

Comment: contextlib has a redirect_stdout out of the box. Is there any reason you didn't use this in your solution? Seems to work well.

Comment: @julianhatwell Well, the answer is 10 years old, it didn't exist back then :-) I've added your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can redirect the standard output to a string for the duration of the exec call:

### Python2

```
import sys
from cStringIO import StringIO

code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i:
    print(j)
"""

old_stdout = sys.stdout
redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
exec(code)
sys.stdout = old_stdout

print(redirected_output.getvalue())
```

### Python3

```py
import sys
from io import StringIO

code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i:
    print(j)
"""

old_stdout = sys.stdout
redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
exec(code)
sys.stdout = old_stdout

print(redirected_output.getvalue())
```

Comment: Just wanted to add the note that to make this Python 3 friendly, you have to import `StringIO` from `io` =>  `from io import StringIO`.

Answer (score 13):

Here is Py3-friendly version of @Jochen's answer. I also added `try-except` clause to recover in case of errors in the `code`.

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdoutIO(stdout=None):
    old = sys.stdout
    if stdout is None:
        stdout = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = stdout
    yield stdout
    sys.stdout = old

code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
    print(j)
"""
with stdoutIO() as s:
    try:
        exec(code)
    except:
        print("Something wrong with the code")
print("out:", s.getvalue())
```

Comment: Why yield? As opposed to what sergzach is doing below you?

Comment: any ideas about why this fails for me under Python 3.4? (always same error, no matter what I put inside my print function):    _Something wrong with the code:
print() argument after * must be a sequence, not map_

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small correction of Frédéric's answer. We need to handle a possible exception in `exec()` to return back normal `stdout`. Otherwise we could not see farther `print` outputs:

```
code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
print j
"""

from cStringIO import StringIO
old_stdout = sys.stdout
redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
try:
    exec(code)
except:
    raise 
finally: # !
    sys.stdout = old_stdout # !

print redirected_output.getvalue()
...
print 'Hello, World!' # now we see it in case of the exception above
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3: Get the output of the exec into a variable

```
import io, sys
print(sys.version)

#keep a named handle on the prior stdout 
old_stdout = sys.stdout 
#keep a named handle on io.StringIO() buffer 
new_stdout = io.StringIO() 
#Redirect python stdout into the builtin io.StringIO() buffer 
sys.stdout = new_stdout 

#variable contains python code referencing external memory
mycode = """print( local_variable + 5 )""" 

local_variable = 2
exec(mycode)

#stdout from mycode is read into a variable
result = sys.stdout.getvalue().strip()

#put stdout back to normal 
sys.stdout = old_stdout 
 
print("result of mycode is: '" + str(result) + "'")
```

Prints:

```
3.4.8
result of mycode is: '7'
```

Also a reminder that python `exec(...)` is evil and bad because 1. It makes your code into unreadable goto-spaghetti.  2. Introduces end-user code injection opportunities, and 3. Throws the exception stacktrace into chaos because exec is made of threads and threads are bad mmkay.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
 codeproc = subprocess.Popen(code, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 print(codeproc.stdout.read())
```

should execute the code in a different process and pipe the output back to your main program via `codeproc.stdout`. But I've not personally used it so if there's something I've done wrong feel free to point it out :P

Comment: i've got a :
    codeproc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\DEV\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\DEV\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 882, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable (file not found in french)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine exec with eval to get an output as list:

```
ExecString('i = [0,1,2]');
println(EvalStr('[j for j in i]'));
```