# Execute a block of python code with exec, capturing all its output?

Tags: python, dynamic, io, exec

What's a good way to exec a bunch of python code, like `exec mycode`, and capture everything it prints to stdout into a string?

Comment: Have a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906232/python-get-the-print-output-in-an-exec-statement/3906390#3906390 It is replacing stdout for the time of execution.

Comment: @Reiner: Although this question is worded better, it's basically a dup of that one (and that one has a fantastic answer!).  Should this be closed & pointed to that one?

Comment: ah i thought of doing something like that then decided it wouldnt work for some reason , but i guess not!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try replacing the default sys.stdout, like in this snippet:

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
sys.stdout = buffer

exec "print 'Hello, World!'"

#remember to restore the original stdout!
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

print buffer.getvalue()
```