# exec() with StringIO() in python

Tags: python

I would like to change the standard output from a terminal to a string.
I could use the instruction by Frédéric Hamidi in the web page:
[python: get the print output in an exec statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906232/python-get-the-print-output-in-an-exec-statement)
, and it works. However, if I would like to run ping command, I couldn't reach to specific char in in the string. there is an error which is `"IndexError: string index out of range"` 
I would be grateful if you can help me with this problem.

Thanks a lot
  Anees

The code:

```
import sys
from cStringIO import StringIO
import subprocess

code2 ="""
subprocess.call(['ping','www.google.com','-n','1'])
"""

old_stdout = sys.stdout
redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
exec(code2)
sys.stdout = old_stdout
x= redirected_output.getvalue()
print x
print x[10]
redirected_output.close()
```

Comment: You're putting python code in a string and then trying to exec it. Use subprocess or exec, not both at once, that makes no sense.

Comment: What was wrong with just calling `subprocess.call(['ping', 'www.google.com', '-n', '1'])`?

Comment: You got len(x) is 0.