# How to get execution of python print statements as a string?

Tags: python, exec

I am writing a python script which contains a list containing python print statements as a string. In my function, I am using a for loop to run exec function to run those statements.

Here is my function:

```
g_list = ["print('Wow!')\n", "print('Great!')\n", "print('Epic!')\n"]

def run_statements():
    for item in g_list:
        exec(item)
```

When I run `run_statements()` function, I get the following output:

```
Wow! 
Great! 
Epic!
```

Basically, I want to save the output as a string so that later, I can save it to my database.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do it?

**EDIT:** At the following question: [python: get the print output in an exec statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906232/python-get-the-print-output-in-an-exec-statement) He is trying to get output, My question is different in a way that I am trying to get output as a string

Comment: The point of `print` is to send text somewhere, not to save it in memory. If you want to save that as a string, you should simply do so, and then print it when appropriate. Also, it's likely that `exec` is the wrong approach for whatever goal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you give an exact sample output of what you're expecting the final result to be? You said a string`. So you want: `"Wow!\nGreat!\nEpic\n"`?

Comment: @idjaw yes! thats exactly what I want

Comment: @idjaw it gives syntax error that way

Comment: @Elisha512 Look at the duplicate that was posted.

Comment: @idjaw the other question posted here is a bit confusing for me. Can you explain how will it integrate in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need a `print` statement in the list of strings (as opposed to a print-like function with a different name, as suggested in another answer), you can reassign the name `print` to your own function, after carefully, carefully, carefully saving the old print function so you can carefully, carefully, carefully restore the name `print` to its proper definition. Like this:

```
>>> g_list = ["print('Wow!')\n", "print('Great!')\n", "print('Epic!')\n"]
>>> old_print = print
>>> def print(s): # redefining the built-in print function! terrible idea
...   global catstr
...   catstr += s
...
>>> catstr = ""
>>> for s in g_list: exec(s)
...
>>> catstr
'Wow!Great!Epic!'
>>> print = old_print # Don't forget this step!
```

This is completely immoral, and I did not advise you to do it. I only said you *can* do it.

To stress the inadvisability of this plan: `exec` should be used rarely; it is dangerous; reassigning the names of built-in functions to different functions should be done very rarely; it is dangerous. Doing both in the same code could really ruin your day, especially after a maintenance programmer edits your code "just a little," without realizing the potential impact.

Comment: thankyou @D-Von I understand the dangers of it but it might be something exactly what I am looking for. I will test it and if works alright will mark it as correct

Comment: this statement gives out error: old_print = print that invalid syntax

Comment: Are you on Python 3.x? That's where I ran the code. It won't work on Python 2.x, where `print` is a built-in command, not a function.

Comment: do you have any solution in mind for python 2. I am using python 2.7.11

Comment: it works perfectly correct in python 3. I have checked but it doesn't work when I include this in a function. I have added it as update to this answer. Can you please check?

Comment: I can't think of any way of making the same idea work in Python 2. What about the two ideas in the linked answer? They are: (1) changing sys.stdout to an object that writes to a string; and (2) sending the output outside the process on stdout, grabbing it on an I/O pipe, and sending it back into the process.

Comment: can you check the problem I have written as UPDATE at the end of question and guide me please?

Comment: That update isn't going to help. There is no way to fix the problem, as far as I know. You can't replace the built-in `print` statement in Python 2. I think you need to take the time to understand the two ideas in the linked answer. They both seem workable to me.

Comment: No no, I have upgraded my python to 3. And in IDLE, your solution is working but it is not working within a function

Comment: Put `global print` near the top of the function. You can't refer to a name outside the function without telling Python that that is what you're up to. Along the same lines, you don't show where you set `catstr=""`, but if it's global, you will need to say `global catstr`, and if it's inside `execute`, which is where it should be, you will need to say `nonlocal catstr`. You should look up these `global` and `nonlocal` keywords and understand how they affect the visibility of names inside a function, when the names are outside the function.

Comment: can you please update the answer with the corrected function. I am really confused right now

Comment: I don't want to write for you the exact code that you need, because you won't learn anything that way. I want you to think about the problem. Please look up the uses of the `global` and `nonlocal` keywords, then explain what problem they solve and how that problem occurs in your function. I am happy to help you some more after that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save what you print, you could create a custom command, and save the output to a variable. For example

```
output_bin = ""

def printsave(string):
    print string
    if len(string) > 1:
        if string[-2] == "\n":
            output_bin = output_bin + string
        else:
            output_bin = output_bin + string + "\n"
    else:
        output_bin = output_bin + string + "\n
```

Then, whenever you call `printsave()` it is saved to the string `output_bin`. And if you want it to be saved to an array...

```
output_bin = []

def printsave(string):
    print string
    if len(string) > 1:
        if string[-2] == "\n":
            output_bin.append(string)
        else:
            output_bin.append(string + "\n")
    else:
        output_bin.append(string + "\n)
```

Comment: That's not valid Python syntax. This is not correct.

Comment: @idjaw Sorry, I didn't test it at all. :/

Comment: @idjaw What did I do wrong? If you would be as king as to tell me.

Comment: You can't use hyphens in Python. I strongly suggest testing the code to make sure it is a working solution as to not mislead the OP down a path of code that might not be working.