# Accessing the output of a Python program

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, bitvector

I am using `BitVector` in Python. I have to perform *division* over two bit vectors.

I have used the code below:

```
from BitVector import*
mod = BitVector( bitstring='1011011' )
n = 6
a = BitVector( intVal = 9223372036854775809 )
quotient, remainder = a.gf_divide(mod, n)
print(quotient)
print(remainder)
```

The output that I am getting is the following:

```
0000001011111100101010001100111101110101101001101100010010000111

0000
```

I want to convert `quotient` into a list. I can not use the command `list{quotient}` as quotient is not a string. `print(type(quotient))` gives the output `<class 'BitVector.BitVector.BitVector'>`.

How can I convert `quotient` in to a `list` ?

Comment: Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460882/how-to-get-execution-of-python-print-statements-as-a-string) directly answers your question, it's likely not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about `list(str(quotinent))`?

Comment: Not working as I am getting symbols along with the binary bits in the list.