# How to put a variable in a list which is created inside a for loop with exec function

Tags: python, list, exec

After creating some loop variables with exec, I dont know how to put them in a list, see below

```
for i in range(2):
   exec("x%i=i"%i)  #Here I created the variables x0 and x1
   y.append(??????) #I dont know how to put the above variables inside this list in the same loop
print(y)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: get the print output in an exec statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906232/python-get-the-print-output-in-an-exec-statement)

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/access-environment-variables-from-python?