# Retain environment of helper python script in main script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I've one helper script which I want to call from main script which is acting as a Server. This main script looks like this:

```
Class Stuff():
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.log = {}

    def execute(self, filename):
        execfile(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #start this script as server
    clazz = Stuff()
    #here helper_script name will be provided by client at runtime
    clazz.execute(helper_script)
```

Now Client will invoke this helper script by providing it's name to main script(Server). After execution I want to retain variables of helper script (i.e: a,b) in main script. I know one way is to return those variables from helper script to main script. But is there any other way so to retain all variables of helper script. This is how helper script looks like:

```
import os
a = 3
b = 4
```

I tried using execfile and subprocess.

Comment: Just import your _helper_ script instead of calling it as a subprocess...

Comment: This is not an elegant solution, but you can have the helper script write the variables to a file (text, csv, pickle, json) and then have the main script read from the file.

Comment: @zwer import doesn't execute script, I need to call some function after that to execute that script.

Comment: @caseWestern yeah I thought of that but that doesn't look clean.

Comment: @Khatri - `import helper_script` in your Python code will do exactly the same thing as `python helper_script.py` from the CLI for your example script, and for any other script that doesn't have `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard or doesn't check/depend on the environment in other ways.

Comment: What's the problem with `execfile()`?

Comment: Actually my main script is a python server which has a class having a function which calls the execfile command, so main script(server) is not able to retain the context of helper script.

Comment: I think you need to put more information about the circumstances of your problem into the question. Because the question as written sounds like a job for `exec()`/`execfile()`.

Comment: @glibdud I've edited the details of problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you do `from helper_script import *` ?

Comment: As you mentioned above, just return the variables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a locals dictionary to `execfile`. After executing the file, this dictionary will contain the local variables it defined.

```
class Stuff():
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = {}

    def execute(self, filename):
        client_locals = {}
        execfile(filename, globals(), client_locals)
        return client_locals

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #start this script as server
    clazz = Stuff()
    #here helper_script name will be provided by client at runtime
    client_locals = clazz.execute('client.py')
    print(client_locals)
```

With your `client.py`, this will print:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'os': <module 'os' from '/Users/.../.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>}
```

A word of warning on `execfile`: don't use it with files from untrusted sources.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should `return` the value(s) from the helper script. If there is more than one, stick it in a list or dictionary (`namedtuple` is handy for this).

The key is that you need to assign the result of `execfile` to a variable in the server script. This doesn't have to be anything major, it can just be dumped straight into a collection such as a list.

## Return-based code

### Main file

```
class Stuff():
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.log = {}
        self.storage = []

    def execute(self, filename):
        self.storage.append(execfile(filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #start this script as server
    clazz = Stuff()
    #here helper_script name will be provided by client at runtime
    clazz.execute(helper_script)
```

### Helper file (helper.py)

```
a = 3
b = 4
return (a, b)
```

## Stdout alternative

An alternative approach would be to have the helper file print the results but redirect `stdout`. This is fairly trivial if you are using `subprocess` and is well detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) (I can add an example if it would be beneficial). I'm less familiar with the `exec / execfile` approach than `subprocess` but there is an explanation on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906232/python-get-the-print-output-in-an-exec-statement).

In case anything happens to the other SO question, copied here is the code for the two examples:

### Frédéric Hamidi

```
    code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
print j
"""

from cStringIO import StringIO
old_stdout = sys.stdout
redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
exec(code)
sys.stdout = old_stdout

print redirected_output.getvalue()
```

### Jochen Ritzel

```
import sys
import StringIO
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdoutIO(stdout=None):
    old = sys.stdout
    if stdout is None:
        stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = stdout
    yield stdout
    sys.stdout = old

code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
    print j
"""
with stdoutIO() as s:
    exec code

print "out:", s.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Hepper Thanks for the clean explanation.In the case of Python3.x the execfile is not supported. you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/437857/1790603

Answer (score 0):

You can access all symbols (variables, classes, methods...) that you defined in any given namespace using the `locals()` method. Here's an example

```
import os
a = 1
b = 2
return locals()
```

will yield a dict containing (among some technical stuff)

```
{'os': <module 'os' from '...'>, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

So, if saved the above in a file called `foo.py`, you could work with this value like this:

```
foo_vals = execfile(`foo.py`)
print(foo_vals["a"])
> 1
```

But that is not the approach I'd go with. Depending on the amount of code in your script, that dictionary is *huge* and cluttered with stuff you don't need, and I would only ever use it for debugging purposes. Here are other options, ordered by "good coding practice":

1. Put your code inside a class that you import and then initialize & run to your liking, keeping all relevant variables inside that class's namespace.
2. You could call `import foo` and then access `a` and `b` with `foo.a`, `foo.b`. (You can call `import foo` anywhere inside your code though I think it will only execute once).
3. Explicitly return the variables in your script that you need, then exec it with `execfile`