# Python 3 I'd like my exec function to resolve to a string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

```
line1 = "class A:\n\tpass"
line2 = "class B:\n\tpass" 
line3 = "class C:\n\tpass"
line4 = "print(issubclass(C,A) and issubclass(C,B))"
```

`exec(line1...4)` results in `"False"` printed to the console, as it should be.

However, if I then:

```
myList = [str(exec(line4))]
print(myList)
```

The string in myList is `"None"`, where I'd like it to be `"False"` as printed on the console.

I've tried `aVariable = exec(line4)` but this also prints "None".

Any help welcome.

I'm new to Python and I feel like there's a nuance I'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Executing a line is not the same as **evaluating** it. There is an [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function (which you should also be careful about using in real code).

Comment: If you are new to Python, you should absolutely *not* be using `exec` or `eval`.

Comment: Upvoted you, @chepner because it's true for real code, but the best way to learn how something works is to play with it extensively.

Comment: `exec` and `eval` are far, *far* down the list of things you need to know right now.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure I don't _need_ to know them, but the best time to start learning about anything, in any field, is the moment in which interest is piqued. Whilst `exec` and `eval` are certainly a diversion from my current curriculum, they're certainly also being a welcome and informative one. If you're offering to help me achieve my learning goals, I'd certainly welcome your input, @chepner, if your reputation is anything to go by. PM if you'd like a tutee and we can have a chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***printing*** is not the same as ***returning***. As per the documentation, [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) **always** returns `None`:

> [...] The return value is `None`.

Using something like [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) won't help you either, because your line evaluates to `None` as well (I repeat: *printing* is not the same as *returning*)

If you want to actually capture what's being printed, then take a look at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906232/python-get-the-print-output-in-an-exec-statement)

---

If what you want is to actually *return* instead of *print*, then change your line accordingly:

```py
line4 = "issubclass(C,A) and issubclass(C,B)"
```

And then, use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```py
myValue = eval(line4)
# myValue = False
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's answered my question! Schoolboy error on my part!

Answer (score -1):

You want eval instead of exec, as to why you are doing this I can not understand it but will not ask: (Also your line4 will never evaluate to a boolean, as it is a print which also returns none):

```
line4 = 'myList = [str(issubclass(C,A) and issubclass(C,B))]'
```

exec the first lines to create your classes, then eval line4:
 FOR SOME REASON LIST COMPREHENSION DOES NOT ASSIGN, SO:

```
exec(line1)
exec(line2)
exec(line3)
exec(line4)

myList
```

Out[44]: ['False']

Comment: Using `eval` doesn't change anything, the line itself does not return anything, it's just printing.

Comment: yeye need to assign the variable inside the eval string , give me a minute

Comment: wow what is it with the downvoting, he can perfectly do what he is doing with strings, as long as he assigns the result to a var inside the expression he evaluates/execs

Comment: My downvote was for the original version of your answer. I've removed it.

Comment: Thanks, this answer also solved my problem and jogged my memory about something I should have remembered!