# Run a dynamic multi-line string of code in python at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic

How can I run a multi-line string of code from inside python, additionally the string is generated at runtime and stored in either a string or an array.

**Background**

- I have a function which dynamically generates random code snippets in high volume.
- I wish to pass this code to a variable/string and evaluate syntax/return code.
- Code can not be imported from file/api request etc as focus is on high throughput and speed.

**Example**

```
# my function returns random code snippets
myCode = myRandomCodeGenerator()

# I wish to perform some in fight validation (ideally RC or syntax)
someTestingFunction(myCode)
```

**My attempts so far**

I have seen solutions such as the one below, however since my code is generated dynamically I have issues formatting. I have tried generating \n and \r or adding """ in the string to compensate with no luck.

```
code = """
def multiply(x,y):
    return x*y

print('Multiply of 2 and 3 is: ',multiply(2,3))
"""

exec(code)
```

I have also tried using the `call` function on a string yields similar formatting issues.

So far the best I can do is to perform a line by line syntax check and feed it a line at a time as shown below.

```
import codeop
def is_valid_code(line):
    try:
        codeop.compile_command(line)
    except SyntaxError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I suspect there may be some syntax tricks I could apply to preserve formatting of indentation and returns. I am also aware of the risk of generating dynamic code in runtime, and have a filter of allowed terms in the function.

Comment: how do you expect it to do anything if you cant get your spacing formatted correctly ... ? spacing is very important to python... i think this is an XY problem... where you are doing X to solve Y, but there is a much better path to Y... also whatever safeties you think you have in place... if this is user input data you are gonna get owned if someone really wants to

Comment: I agree, is there a way to preserve spacing/indentation when generated dynamically? The exec example i listed works fine when input manually.

Comment: it(`exec`) does not modify the whitespace ... so generate code that has valid spacing

Comment: I already have, call and exec functions does not seem to recognise it. I validated this manually when passed to a string, is there a dynamic way to preserve multiple lines in a string, as in the triple quote method.

Comment: your example above is a triple quoted string... and it works ... I guess i don't understand what you are asking

Comment: `exec("def multiply(x,y):\n    return x*y\nprint('Multiply of 2 and 3 is: ',multiply(2,3))\n")` is the equivelent of the triple quoted string above, without triple quotes

Comment: Thank you Joran, I see where my code was failing; an automatic space was added after every \n as a safety margin. Even in the example above it fails if the print statement looks like this `return x*y\n print('Multiply of 2 and 3 is:`  
Much appreciated and I see both the reason and that this is now possible - thanks again.

Comment: I did not see the obvious uin the above comments - or in the answer - but you are aware that using the `\n` special sequence in a code string will generate a newline character, don't you? Adding a  `\n`  to the end of a line is all that is needed for a multiline script.

Comment: Thanks Jsbueno, yes I think my issue was I wasn't sure it was even possible, and I was deliberately adding a space after the `\n` such as `\n print(..)` to avoid it being read as a single unit. I didn't realise python accounted for this. As such it was giving me errors anytime when defining a function.

Answer (score 1):

Another way instead of `eval` and `exec` is to compile the code before and then to exec it:

Example:

```
import contextlib,sys
from io import StringIO 
@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdoutIO(stdout=None):
    old = sys.stdout
    if stdout is None:
        stdout = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = stdout
    yield stdout
    sys.stdout = old


def run_code(override_kale_blocks):
    compiled123 = []
    for b123 in override_kale_blocks:
        compiled123.append(compile(b123,"<string>","exec"))
    
    with stdoutIO() as s:
        for c123 in compiled123:
            exec(c123)
    return s.getvalue()
    


block0='''
import time
a=5
b=6
b=a+b
'''
block1='''
b=a+b
'''
block2="print(b)"
blocksleep='''
print('startsleep')
time.sleep(1)
print('donesleep')
'''
pc  = (block0,blocksleep,block1,block2)
cb = []
print('before')
output= run_code(pc)
print(output)
print('after')
print("Hello World!\n")
```

source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906390/1211174

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered by Joran Beasley.

Essentially, my issue was I was adding a space after `\n` as other compilers get confused, python however takes this into account. 
Thus if you add a space after a return carriage in a def statement, it will produce syntax error.

I have kept this incase others encounter similar issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try using '\t' instead of placing tabs and spaces for the indentation, that may preserve your formatting.

```
code = """
def multiply(x,y):
\t return x*y

print('Multiply of 2 and 3 is: ',multiply(2,3))
"""
exec(code)
```

Comment: `\t` simply expands to a tab character - even in generated code it should be avoided, as there are several pitfalls.