# How can I get the output of a function without the 'return' statement?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have recently been building a discord bot that is, apart from being a small IDE, trains and teaches you Python, by asking you questions about it. But I am stuck on the IDE part. The problem is that the functions in Python used for executing code inside of code are terminal-based and don't return the code they evaluate. Here are some functions I've tried:

- Exec()
- Eval()
- Subprocess.call()

My code so far looks like this:

```py
import discord
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
client = discord.Client()
global new_content
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm in")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global new_content
  if message.author != client.user:
    if message.content == "!help":
      await message.channel.send(f'''**---- HELP OPTIONS ----**
      Prefix: `!`
      To train: `!train`
      To start new IDE file: `!start`
      To open an old IDE file: `!open`
      To run an IDE file: `!run`''')
    elif message.content == "!start":
      new_content = ''
      await message.channel.send("Write your Python code!! Leave RUN to end")
      @client.event
      async def on_message(message):
        global new_content
        if message.author != client.user:
          if message.content == "RUN":
            code = str(eval(new_content))
            await message.channel.send(f'''**---- OUTPUT ----**
            {code}''')
          else:
            print(message.content)
            new_content = new_content + str(message.content)
keep_alive() #To keep bot running forever
token = os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_SECRET")
client.run(token)
```

But when I type in `!start` and type up some code the result looks like this:

```
---- OUTPUT ----
      None
```

I think this is because the functions don't return what they output/print(). Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you use this https://stackoverflow.com/q/3906232/1515394

Comment: @darkspine, yes I can, thank you!