# Is there any way I can print the output of a code to a tkinter text box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a python IDE and I wanted to print the output of a file's code to the output text box.
My current code doesnt work, it executes in the shell and the output is to the box is "None".
Code:

```
from tkinter import *
input_box = Text()
output_box = Text()
def execute():
    code = input_box.get(1.0, END)
    out = exec(code)
    output.insert(1.0, str(out))
```

Comment: try `eval` instead of `exec`... `eval` can return a value where `exec` does not

Comment: But does eval work with every type of code? Also thanks

Comment: It give me an error

Comment: "args should be '.23918448 insert index chars ?tagList chars tagList

Comment: "print the output of a file's code" is not a well defined goal, most code doesn't output anything unless it contains e.g. `print` call. `exec("print('hello')")` works but you will need to capture stdout rather than return value

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by redirecting the standard output as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906309/7519434).

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
def execute():
    code = input_box.get(1.0, "end")
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
    exec(code)
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    output_box.delete(1.0, "end")
    output_box.insert(1.0, redirected_output.getvalue())
```

Comment: Lemme try that a

Comment: It says StringIO is not defined @Henry

Comment: Forgot to import wait